# Looping a function within a module

Tags: python, function, loops

I am having real trouble with a program I am attempting to write. The code as shown below is supposed to ask the user for the input and then print the result continuously until an illegal value is entered. In my code design I can either make the answer loop infinitely or as shown below, ask twice and quit. How can I loop this function to do what I want? Many many thanks!

```
#define the function getLetterGrade and enter conditions of the function

def getLetterGrade (numGrade):
    if numGrade >= 95 and numGrade <= 100:
        print (" A+")
    elif numGrade >= 90 and numGrade <95:
        print (" A")
    elif numGrade >= 85 and numGrade <90:
        print (" A-")
    elif numGrade >= 80 and numGrade <85:
        print (" B+")
    elif numGrade >= 75 and numGrade <80:
        print (" B")
    elif numGrade >= 70 and numGrade <75:
        print (" B-")
    elif numGrade >= 65 and numGrade <70:
        print (" C+")
    elif numGrade >= 60 and numGrade <65:
        print (" C")
    elif numGrade >= 55 and numGrade <60:
        print (" C-")
    elif numGrade >= 50 and numGrade <55:
        print (" P")
    elif numGrade < 50 and numGrade >=0:
        print (" F")
    elif numGrade < 0 or numGrade > 100:
        print (" invalid, please enter a score between 0 and 100.")

def main():
    #Ask the user for input


    numGrade = eval(input("Enter your mark in percent"))
    while numGrade >= 0 or numGrade <= 100:
        print("The grade for", numGrade, "is", end = '')
        getLetterGrade(numGrade) # Call the function getLetterGrade as defined above
        break
    numGrade = eval(input("Enter your mark in percent"))
    while numGrade >= 0 or numGrade <= 100:
        print("The grade for", numGrade, "is", end = '')
        getLetterGrade(numGrade) # Call the function getLetterGrade as defined above
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `eval` on the user's input?

Comment: `eval(input("Enter your mark in percent"))` <--- this is a bad idea and is dangerous

Comment: I am new to programming, the reason I used the eval function is so that the variable becomes and integer rather than a string. What is the alternative? Thanks guys! @JoranBeasley

Comment: I have altered my code to say int(input("Enter....)). I assume this will stop users being able to enter malicious code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# Loop until the mark inserted is not correct
numGrade = input("Enter your mark in percent")
while numGrade >= 0 or numGrade <= 100:
    print("The grade for", numGrade, "is", end = '')
    getLetterGrade(numGrade) # Call the function getLetterGrade as defined above
    numGrade = input("Enter your mark in percent")
print "Invalid mark. Bye!".
```

Comment: `eval(input(...))` seems dangerous to me. What if the user enters `os.system("rm -rf /")` ?

Comment: OP wants the loop to stop when an illegal result is entered and continue when a valid result is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while True` and break from the loop when an illegal value is entered.

```
def main():
    while True:
        num_grade = input("Enter your mark in percent")
        if num_grade < 0 or num_grade > 100:
            break
        print("The grade for", num_grade, "is", end = '')
        get_letter_grade(num_grade)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help, I had not seen the "while true" function before. That really helps. @Stuart

Comment: instead of `break` in a function, I usually `return`. Also you might want to make that `int(input(...))`

Answer (score -1):

my solution

```
>>> def get_grade_input():
...     val = int(raw_input("Enter Grade:"))
...     return val if 0 <= val <= 100 else -1
...
>>> grades = list(iter(get_grade_input,-1))
>>> def get_grade(pct_grade):
...    return "FDCBA"[(pct_grade-50)//10]
...
>>> get_grade(66)
'D'
>>> get_grade(73)
'C'
```